# How to define custom margins to StepperLayout navigation buttons

Tags: java, android, xml, stepper

I have a StepperLayout that displays a list of questions to the users. However, half of the "NEXT" navigation button is hidden after giving it a background color. I want to define custom margins and alignments to the navigation buttons. See the gif image below.

[image: Current StepperLayout gif image]

I have tried overriding the codes used for the NEXT and BACK button but that displays duplicate buttons. I have also tried adding some paddings to the StepperLayout but still, it didn't help.

```
        <com.stepstone.stepper.StepperLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/stepper"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:ms_activeStepColor="@color/stepper_btn_blue"
            app:ms_nextButtonBackground="@color/stepper_btn_blue"
            app:ms_backButtonColor="#000000"
            app:ms_completeButtonColor="@color/colorWhite"
            app:ms_completeButtonText="Finish"
            app:ms_stepperType="tabs"
            tools:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
```